# Is it possible to declare a class variable that will yield the sum of two other class variables

Tags: python, oop

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ref        = 0
        self.ask        = 0
        self.added      = self.ref + self.ask 

inst = my_class()
inst.ref   = 5
inst.ask   = 7
print(inst.ref + inst.ask)
print(inst.added)
```

I would like `print(inst.added)` to return 12 but it returns 0

Comment: A note about your terminology: these are _instance_ variables, not class variables. A class variable would have a value that is shared among all instances of the class, and is less commonly used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the method whose name is `__init__` is called just after the class is created (cf `__new__`). Which means that when you do

```
inst = my_class()
```

`inst.added` already equals `0` whatever you do afterward.

The thing you can do is defining another method which does what you need when you need it (and so after the instantiation). E.g.

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ref = 0
        self.ask = 0

    @property
    def added(self):
        return self.ref + self.ask

    def add(self):
        return self.ref + self.ask
```

And finally

```
>>> inst = my_class()
>>> inst.ref = 5
>>> inst.ask = 7
>>> inst.added # briefly, the property decorator does the job of calling the callable for you 
12
>>> inst.add() # while here, you do call the callable
12
>>> inst.ref = 7
>>> inst.added
14
>>> inst.add()
14
```

However, keep in mind that even if you can access `added` as a common attribute, you will get an error if you try to set it directly (in Python 2 as well as in version 3), i.e.

```
>>> inst.added = 15
```

returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#XX>", line YY, in <module>
    inst.added = 15
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to make `added` a method and call it:

```
>>> class A:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.ref = 0
...       self.ask = 0
...    def added(self):
...       return self.ref + self.ask
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.ref = 5
>>> a.ask = 7
>>> a.added()
12
>>>
```

Or you can make `added` a property, which let's you access it like a data attribute instead of a method:

```
>>> class A:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.ref = 0
...       self.ask = 0
...    @property
...    def added(self):
...       return self.ref + self.ask
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.ref = 5
>>> a.ask = 7
>>> a.added
12
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `self.added      = self.ref + self.ask`, this takes the **current values** of `self.ref` and `self.ask` and adds them together immediately at the time this line executes. `self.added` will not be updated when you change `self.ref` or `self.ask`. Instead, you need to make a function in your class to set these values:

```
class my_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ref        = 0
        self.ask        = 0
        self.added      = self.ref + self.ask 

    def set_ref(self, value):
        self.ref = value
        self.added = self.ref + self.ask

inst = my_class()
inst.set_ref(5)
print(inst.added)
```

Comment: generally, in Python, one doesn't use getters and setters.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, your `@property` solution is much more pythonic.